# Plotly Choropleth data missing after exporting to html file

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python, choropleth

I am plotting data on a choropleth map using the geojson map of India. The map output is proper(no missing data) when I run it on a google Colab notebook but if I export the plot as an html file it misses a particular State on the map. Please help am I missing something here?

**this is the  image of plot output on colab notebook :**
[notebook output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqtAu.png)

**and this is how it looks if exported as a html file:**
[ouput if exported as a html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOnMW.png)

**as you can see one of the State in the middle shows no data**

code: (I don't think the problem is in my code as it displays correct plot on notebook but still I am attaching it below)

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df,
    locations="id",
    geojson=india_geojson,
    color="Cases",
    hover_name="States",
    hover_data=["Cases","Recovered","Active", "Deaths", "Date"],
    title="Heat Map of Covid Cases in India",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    color_continuous_scale='Inferno_r',
    center={"lat": 24, "lon": 78},
    zoom=3,
    opacity=1,
)
fig.update_layout(height=580,width=600, plot_bgcolor='rgb(248,249,252)', paper_bgcolor='rgb(248,249,252)',)
fig.show()
```